# What's the notations $\mathbb{B}_I$ and $g_{\infty,l}(\Delta, u,v)$ in the Zamolodchikov recursion relations?

Tags: definition, conformal-field-theory

Weizmann Lectures on the Numerical Conformal Bootstrap 1907.05147 Eq. 3.19
\begin{equation}
g_{\Delta,l}(u,v)=
g_{\infty,l}(\Delta, u,v)+\sum_{I}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{B}_{I}} \frac{c_{I,m}}{\Delta-\Delta_{I,m}} g_{\Delta_{I,m}+m,l_{I,m}}(u,v)
\end{equation}

What's the set $\mathbb{B}_I$?

Also, wasn't
\begin{equation}
g_{\infty,l}(\Delta, u,v) =\lim_{\Delta'\rightarrow \infty} g_{\Delta',l}(u,v)
\end{equation}
? But how does $g_{\infty,l}(\Delta, u,v)$ has an argument of $\Delta$?

Comment: Your questions are answered by Eq. 3.20 and Table 2 right below.

Comment: @ConnorBehan (didn't notice that) for the value of $l$ I thought the whole point of the Zamolodchikov recursion relations was so that the odd $d$ could be calculated, and does the even $l$ still hold in that case?

Comment: Which spins $\ell$ are allowed is unrelated to the number of dimensions $d$. Here, spins are even because the recursion relations are being given for a 4pt function of identical scalars. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4858 for the generalization to non-identical scalars.